# Query returns non-empty dataset in bigquery web UI, but empty set in python script

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I ran a query on bigquery's website and it returned 201 rows. I am running the same query in a python script and it is returning an empty dataset. But the column names are returned correctly.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from pandas import*

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'service-acc-creds.json')
project_id = 'coral-silicon-237417'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
query = """
  SELECT
  *
FROM
  `fh-bigquery.reddit.top25million` 
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(title, r'(?i)\bVonnegut\b') OR REGEXP_CONTAINS(title, r'(?i)\bKurt Vonnegut\b')
  ORDER BY score DESC;"""

query_job = client.query(query)
results = query_job.result().to_dataframe() 
print(results.to_string())
```

Comment: I think if you run `results = query_job.result()`, the property `errors` will be filled in case anything went wrong. You could try printing `print(results.errors)` to confirm if the query is running correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping in Python is relevant here:

```
client.query("""SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit.top25million`""")
2267097

client.query(
"""SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit.top25million` 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(title, r'(?i)\bVonnegut\b')"""
)
0

client.query(
r"""SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit.top25million` 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(title, r'(?i)\bVonnegut\b')"""
)
201

client.query(
"""SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit.top25million` 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(title, r'(?i)\\bVonnegut\\b')"""
)
201
```